# Appium giving null response when trying to find it inside a scroll view using xpath

Tags: testng, appium, appium-android, testng-eclipse, appium-desktop

I am currently new to appium.
I am trying to click on an item inside the scroll view of my app in which the element is found by xpath.

```
MobileElement el11 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath(
                "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[4]/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[7]/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.widget.TextView");
        System.out.println(el11.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("View More"));
        el11.click();
        System.out.println("Tap performed");
```

Inside the 1st syso statement im getting true. and the seocnd syso statement im getting tap performed.

But inside the appium server log. click() function is returning null. When i tried to tap the item inside the appium inspector the tap results into a navigation of another page.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

To click any element inside scrollable view, it is good to use UIAutomator selector, first to find it and scroll it into viewport visible area, after that you can make a click.

```
MobileElement el11 = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
        "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0))" +
         ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"View More\"))"));
el11.click();
```

As a side note, searching by text is a bad approach since you might have it in different labels. Try to use resource-id whenever it is possible